# Encrypted Add-A-Gram!

Tags: word, cipher, knowledge, anagram

In a regular Add-A-Gram, each word in the chain is an anagram of the previous word plus one additional letter. It is possible to solve them from any entry point, and then work forwards or backwards from there.

I've decided to add encryption to the Add-A-Gram so that it can only be solved incrementally from the beginning. There is a logical and consistent way each clue is encrypted. As you go, there will be no doubt that you are on the right track.

Given the nature of this puzzle, I ask that solutions be withheld until they are complete.

Here is the definition for this Encrypted Add-A-Gram chain:

**a constant speed** *in* **vygpvkgvj qh kvu mkpf** *in*  **c lwmknquu eneettiean dksehcrie** *in* **a ccrxg adquev** *in* **pgkvihp** *in* **ytuzhsg** *in* **vyiexq-vyieh gh ztf oapu** *in* **snwpy** *in* **nyckxefil zgdfrsrm qkjos** *in* **ezaltersw** *in* **hee jzw eqxsvrtrk ir vothjigawr** *in* **sbaqkuoy wiekigkoqhviw** *in* **nexs** *in* **tsyttqak kz e hwvwgbov ssi lrgljse**

Happy Encrypted Add-A-Gramming!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cipher is

> Vignere. Each clue has been encrypted with the previous clue's answer.

Solution:

> [image]